# How to rotate IPv6 per connection on one machine?

Tags: networking, iptables, ipv6

I have allocated /64 subnet from my provider and trying to change my IP per each connection to bypass some rate-limits.

I already tried:
`ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source 2416:b051:9e2c:3fa9::2-2416:b051:9e2c:3fa9::10`

While this command above works (even if I put ::fa instead of ::10), this does not - default IP is used:
`ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source 2416:b051:9e2c:3fa9::2-2416:b051:9e2c:3fa9::140d` (IPs from ::2 to ::140d are connected & reachable, they work if I bind interface explicitly with curl)

Comment: SNAT applies to forwarded traffic only.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen is there any solution?

Comment: What rate limits? Have you discussed your wish to exceed them with the entity that imposed them?

Comment: @JohnMahowald yes, I have all required permissions.

Comment: Not really what I asked. What rate limitations are in place, imposed by whom, and have you talked to those organizations? It can be rude to bypass limits without attempting to negotiate a higher quota based on your use case.